# mouseup function when clicking outside of a div

Tags: jquery, html, mouseevent, parent, fade

I've got a working html page with jquery, with one function that does not work:

I've made a div open ('containerprC') after hiding two divs on the main page ('containerSW' and 'containershort').

What I now want is, for ('containerprC') to fade out when I click only *outside* of the div, and for the hidden divs to fade in.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
if (!$(e.target).is('#containerprC') && !$(e.target).parents().is('#containerprC')) {

    $('#containerprC').fadeOut("slow");
    $('#containerSW').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#containershort').fadeIn('slow');
}
});
```

The fade out and in's work fine, but they happen if I click anywhere on the page, including inside of containerprC.

So it means that the first line (if (!$(e.target).is) is not working properly. 
How could I make it work? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your second condition is wrong. But you can change your entire condition for this one :

```
if (!$(e.target).is('#containerprC, #containerprC *'))
```

It will check if the target is the `div` or one of its children.

Comment: When I use the condition you suggest, none of the original jquery functions work for the html page. So I cannot fade out the other containers and fade in containerprC (the point at which the problem above occurs).

Comment: @LauraMaasry Do you think you can reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thank you but when I use this, the other divs still appear behind.

Comment: I will try to reproduce it for you.

Comment: There was one bracket missing from your advice ')'.

Comment: @LauraMaasry that was my bad, you know fast coding! Thank!

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I had a number of hidden divs (containerprA, containerprB) that were loading the other divs to fade in, even when this condition was corrected. It look a little bit of jquery, organization!